# How to change the color of this line in Rider?

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

I haven't been able to find any tutorial on how to change the color of this line, can you tell me how this can be done?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WziJI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found the required color setting!

[image: settings]